# App Storeにあるアプリをアップデートしようとするとエラーになる

Tags: swift, xcode, swift4, xcode6, app-store

App Store でリリースしたアプリをアップデートするため、いつも通りArchiveを行い、Distribute Appボタンを押してアップデートしようとしたんですが、Xcodeにこのような画面が出て来て、アップデートできませんでした。なぜでしょうか？

回答していただける方がいらっしゃいましたら、よろしくお願いします。

**表示されたメッセージ:**

```
Code signing "FBLPromises.framework" failed.
```

[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

Answer (score 1):

新しく組み込んだ（と思われる）`FBLPromises.framework`が署名されていないためです。

`Terminal`から、プロジェクト中の`FBLPromises.framework`を、`Keychain Access`で開発者の署名を選択し、一行目をコピーして

```
codesign --force --deep-verify --verbose --sign "ここに証明書の名前" --keychain ~/Library/Keychains/login.keychain-db  FBLPromises.framework
```

で署名するとアップロードできるようになると思います。
証明書の名前は（多分） "App Store Application 名前 (X0X...)" の様な文字列です。

[image: 証明書の名前の場所]

Comment: 回答ありがとうございます
証明書の名前を探してんですが、見つかりません
Developer ID Application:A...
っていう証明書を探したんですが、見つかりませんでした
あるのは、
Apple Development: (名前)とApple Distribution:(名前)とiPhone Developer: (名前)

Comment: Apple Distrribution(リリースに使っている証明書の方）です

Comment: Apple Distrubutionのどの部分ですか?
申し訳ありませんが、ちょっとよくわかりませんでした。

Comment: リリースに使っている証明書のタイトル全ての文字列をダブルクォートで括ってください。

Comment: "Apple Distribution: 名前(英数字)"としたんですが、
FBLPromises.framework: No such file or directory
と出てしまいます。

Comment: Terminal コマンド（`codesign`）は、プロジェクトのFBLPromises.frameworkのあるディレクトリで行いましたか？また、このコマンドを実行した後に再度アーカイブが必用です

Comment: cd /Users/名前/Library/Mobile\ Documents/com\~apple\~CloudDocs/Myapp/SwiftDokkiri
のコマンドを打ったあと、(SwiftDokkiriがリリースしているアプリの名前)
 codesign --force --deep-verify --verbose --sign "ここに証明書の名前" --keychain ~/Library/Keychains/login.keychain-db  FBLPromises.framework
を打ちましたがダメでした。

Archiveし直したんですが、ダメでした。

Comment: ダメでしただけではどういうエラーで失敗したかがわからないのでアドバイスしようがありません

Comment: 申し訳ありません。 codesign --force --deep-verify --verbose --sign "ここに証明書の名前" --keychain ~/Library/Keychains/login.keychain-db FBLPromises.framework と打つと、

FBLPromises.framework: No such file or directory

というエラーが発生いたしました。

Comment: それは、`codesign`コマンドをFBLPromises.frameworkがあるディレクトリで実行していないために出るエラーです。実行前にlsでFBLPromises.frameworkがあること、またはスペルミスがないことを確認してから行って下さい。

Comment: FBLPromises.frameworkがどこにあるのかが、わかりません。
一応Finderの検索で探したんですが...
低レベルの質問で申し訳ありません。

Comment: Xcodeのプロジェクトファイル一覧から、FBLPromises.frameworkを探し、右クリックでFinderに表示すれば場所がわかると思うので、あとはそのディレクトリに移動して下さい。エラーコードがFBLPromises.frameworkに署名されていないというエラーなので、プロジェクトにFBLPromises.frameworkは組み込まれているはずです。

Comment: 解決いたしました。
ありがとうございました